# Does jprofiler supports alpine linux?

Tags: java, jprofiler, alpine-linux

Does `jprofiler` work on alpine linux?

`/bin/jpenable` returns:

> ERROR: The agent could not be loaded: Failed to load agent library

Thank you

Comment: You could run `ldd bin\linux-x64\libjprofilerti.so` to check which dependencies are missing.

Comment: How have you installed jprofiler?

Comment: @Ingo Kegel I'll give this one a try. Thank you.

Comment: @Jakub Jirutka running this from the inside of the docker container, by adding jprofiler9 to /usr/local/, from this [post](https://hub.docker.com/r/gingerbeard/java8-jprofiler/~/dockerfile/). Then, running /jpenable -> option 1 -> port 8849 = ERROR: The agent could not be loaded: Failed to load agent library.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  This is an old question, but I'll confirm that I was able to get Jprofiler connected to an alpine 3.5 container.  Detailed instructions for building the baseimage are in my other post:

[UnsatisfiedLinkError when running jpenable in alpine / Jprofile 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50456928/unsatisfiedlinkerror-when-running-jpenable-in-alpine-jprofile-10)